# Dock a Custom VCLStyle Delphi-XE2 application in AvalonDock

Tags: c#, delphi, delphi-xe2, avalondock, vcl-styles

I've an C# application with Avalondock.
In this application I can dock "Third Party" applications like notepad and windows calculator.
In this dock the application window is displayed without the titlebar, just as I want it to be.

I've also an Delphi XE2 Application I want to dock.
This is working correct, the titlebar is removed and the mainmenu is working.
Until I dock the same application with a custom VCL Style. In that case my titlebar stays displayed in the dock and the main menu isn't working anymore.
I can solve the titlebar issue by setting the borderstyle to bsNone.

When I apply the custom style during compilation or runtime during formcreate, formshow or formactivate this issue occurs.
When I apply the style runtime by a button click the mainmenu keeps working, but my window is undocked, I've got an empty dock and an application in front of it.

Does anyone has any ideas how to solve this issue?

Thijs

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue by replacing TMainMenu by TActionManager and TActionMainMenuBar.

A disadvantage of this solution is that the PopulateMenu of the Korzh localizer isn't working anymore. This is no issue for the application when used in a dock, then the localization is set at another level, but will take some work to fix when the application is used undocked.

Thijs